# incompatible integer to pointer conversion "int" to parameter type of "id"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

```
 - (void) changeState
  {

    if ([_buttonChangeState.title isEqual: @"Active"])
    {
        PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
        user[@"active"] = FALSE;
        user[@"party"] = @"";
        [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
        {
            if (error)
            {
                _statusFailed = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Status Change       Error, Try Again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Retry" otherButtonTitles:@"Close", nil];
                _statusFailed.cancelButtonIndex = 0;
                [self.view addSubview:_statusFailed];
            }
            else
            {
                [_buttonChangeState setTitle:@"Taking A Break"];
            }
        }];
    }
    if ([_buttonChangeState.title isEqual:@"Taking A Break"])
    {
       PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
       user[@"active"] = TRUE;
       [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) 
        {
           if(error)
            {
                [self.view addSubview:_statusFailed];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

I am attempting to assign the "active" key field of a Parse user object a bool value, but for some reason when attempting to set user[@"active"] to a TRUE boolean value I receive the error "incompatible integer to pointer conversion "int" to parameter type of "id"". This only happens when setting it to TRUE, setting it to FALSE results in no error. Also, setting it equal to 0 is fine but 1 errors. I am clueless as to why it would matter which boolean value I am attempting to assign. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't add a BOOL into an (effectively dictionary) object. The user object expects to receive another object so your BOOL should be wrapped into an `NSNumber` instance:

```
user[@"active"] = @YES; // NSNumber literal syntax
```

Or

```
user[@"active"] = [NSNumber numberWithBOOL:YES];
```

This applies to both the YES (true) and NO (false) cases.

---

Also, you shouldn't be adding `_statusFailed` As a subview. Call its `show` method to present the alert view.